# How to customize buttons using qtip2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, qtip2

On qtip2 demos page http://qtip2.com/demos: there are buttons under styles and customization section. how to achieve that. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each style is a different CSS class from the `jquery.qtip.css` file.

- `.qtip-shadow` adds the shadow
- `.qtip-rounded` adds the rounded edges
- `.qtip-yellow` adds the yellow color (etc.. etc..)

When you view the uncompressed CSS file. All the class names after `.qtip-default` that are in the first column are style modifiers.

To create a yellow qtip

```
$(".tooltip").qtip({style:{classes: "qtip-yellow"});
```

To apply styles from qtip element

```
<div class="tooltip" data-style="qtip-yellow"/>

$(".tooltip").each(function(){
    $(this).qtip({style:{classes: $(this).data("style")});
});
```

Comment: If we want to add to the content of qtip does we need to apply those classes directly. suppose I have a button like above in image and want to add effect like in above image css3 last button.

Comment: @Cindrella what I do is give the HTML some custom data attributes, and then pass those settings to qtip. see my edit